# Empty all elements in array with pop method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to empty an array by using the pop method after that I want to push the returned result of the pop method to another array and get the full result, but the pop method doesn't satisfy my needs it always stops midway what is the problem?

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

let newArr = []

//console.log(arr.pop())
const fib = function(n){
   if(n <= arr.length){
     newArr.push(arr.pop())
     return fib(n+1)
   }
}

fib(0)

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Think about what's happening to the length of `arr`

Comment: I will appreciate it if you show me results-wise.

Comment: Just use a pencil and a piece of paper.

Comment: Thank you pilchard you are an awesome teacher and instructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like that:

```js
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var myNewArr = [];

while(myArr.length){
  myNewArr.push(myArr.pop());
}

console.log(myArr, myNewArr);
```

If  you just want to reverse it you could use the `reverse` function for Arrays:

```js
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

myArr = myArr.reverse();

console.log(myArr);

// Or if you really need 2 variables and one needs to be empty

var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var myNewArr = myArr.reverse();

myArr = [];

console.log(myArr, myNewArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

let newArr = []

//console.log(arr.pop())
const fib = function(n){
   if(!n <= 0){
     newArr.push(arr.pop())
     return fib(n-1)
   }
}

fib(arr.length)

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your array empy... I think this is the easiest way.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
array = []
console.log(array)
```

Comment: Manesa don't worry you will reach the point where you can give answers.

Comment: well, aside of the part fo the new array, his answer is not wrong